# How do sum decimal numbers in C#?

Tags: c#, command, double

I've tried the code below but it does not work properly. It basically asks user to enter 2 decimal numbers and adds them up. But there is a little problem with it. For example when I enter 1.3 as the first and 2.5 as the second number, the result is 38 instead of 3.8.

```
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
double num3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter another number: ");
double num4 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(num3 + num4);
```

Comment: what is your locale? in some cultures, `.` means "group separator", so `1.3` is thirteen; and `1,3` is one point three; if you're in such a locale, and you want to use a different culture for parsing: you'll need to specify the culture explicitly in `ToDouble` (presumably `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`)

Comment: Hi Mice, you can use `Decimal.Add(num3, num4)`

Comment: @SisindryMedagam that isn't the problem; a: OP isn't using actually `decimal`, and b: the `+` operator works just fine for both `decimal` and `double`

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you sir. As you suggested I tried "," instead of "." and it worked.